# Does IO.File.Copy replicate files attributes?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, .net

Does the `IO.File.Copy` method preserve file attributes? Especially, if I have a write-protected file, will the copy be write-protected to?

Comment: I'm still sure the answer is "no", but I'm going to withdraw my answer and give points to the first person who can show documentation supporting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code proves that file attributes are copied.

```
    Dim sourceFile = "z.txt"
    Dim destinationFile = "x.txt"

    Using sw As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText(sourceFile)
        sw.Write("testing")
    End Using

    IO.File.SetAttributes(sourceFile, IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
    Debug.WriteLine("Source File ReadOnly = " & (IO.File.GetAttributes(sourceFile) And IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly))

    IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile)
    Debug.WriteLine("Destination File ReadOnly = " & (IO.File.GetAttributes(destinationFile) And IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
```

And having just used Reflector I see that IO.File.Copy uses kernel32.dll's CopyFile function which has documentation of what is copied and what is not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851(VS.85).aspx